# how to use maplist and predicates

Tags: prolog

If a predicate has 2 arguments it can be called like this:

```
maplist(member(#),List_of_lists,New).
```

But what if I wanted to call it the other way around, iterating through a list of values to see if any of them belonged in a list I had already? How can i make it so that the elements of the list are not the last argument of the function but rather the first or the second or the third?

EDIT: That code above was an example not what I actually wanted.

```
pal_pos_esps(Letras, Pals_Possiveis, Espacos):-
   maplist(palavras_possiveis_esp(Letras,Espacos,_,Pals_Possiveis),Espacos,Pals_Possiveis).
```

Espacos is a list of list: I want to call each of those lists as the third argument of the predicate. How can I do so?

Comment: Could you show what you expect this to produce?

Comment: That was just an example I've added what I really want above.

Comment: In your first example, `maplist(member(#),List_of_lists,New).` requires the existence of a `member/3`.  Commonly known is `member/2`.

Comment: I present you with my [maplist reader](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/maplist/maplist_2_examples.md)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i make it so that the elements of the list are not the last argument of the function but rather the first or the second or the third?

You could use a lambda construct. In SWi-Prolog there are either library(yall) or library(lambda) (available after you install it with `?- pack_install(lambda).`).

Let's see a basic usage, allocating a matrix NxN, which requires swapping the arguments order of length/2.

With the autoloaded library(yall):

```erlang
matrix(N,M) :- length(M,N), maplist([Row]>>length(Row,N),M).
```

Using library(lambda):

```erlang
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
matrix(N,M) :- length(M,N), maplist(\Row^length(Row,N),M).
```